# How To Add FCKeditor using php

Tags: php

i am new to this FCKeditor,i am using below mentioned code , i am formatting the text in the text editor and display the same text using the echo statement  but it disply only the plain text(without formatting) how to i display the text with formated syntax. please guide me .thanks in advance

```
 <?php
    include("fckeditor.php");

    $sBasePath = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ;
            $sBasePath = substr( $sBasePath, 0, strpos( $sBasePath, "_samples" ) ) ;
            $oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('FCKeditor') ;
            $oFCKeditor->BasePath   = $sBasePath ;
            $oFCKeditor->Value      = $ing ;
            $oFCKeditor->Create() ;
            ?>

<html> 
<head>

<title>Editor</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frmedit" id = "frmedit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
Title &nbsp;:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="txttitle" id = "txttitle">

<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="subsubmit" id="subsubmit" value="SUBMIT">
</form> 
</body>
</html>

<?php
if($_POST["subsubmit"]=="SUBMIT"){
$part2 = $_POST["FCKeditor"];
echo $part2;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Answer Updated]**

You need to put your FCKEditor code inside the `<form> </form>` tags and not at the top. Also, the `$_POST["FCKEditor"]` needs to be put in `$oFCKeditor->Value` variable.

Do it like this: It is working fine on my machine and displays the formatted HTML inside the FCKEditor textarea:

```
<html> 
<head>

<title>Editor</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frmedit" id = "frmedit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
Title &nbsp;:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="txttitle" id = "txttitle">
<?php
    include("fckeditor.php");

    $sBasePath = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ;
            $sBasePath = substr( $sBasePath, 0, strpos( $sBasePath, "_samples" ) ) ;
            $oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('FCKeditor') ;
            $oFCKeditor->BasePath   = $sBasePath ;
            $oFCKeditor->Value      = $_POST["FCKeditor"] ;
            $oFCKeditor->Create() ;
            ?>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="subsubmit" id="subsubmit" value="SUBMIT">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

**Tip: [View more information and complete guide here.](http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Integration/PHP)**

Comment: thank you so much for your reply, i saw the link i am follow the instruction given in that link . Using the $_POST["FCKeditor"] statement i got the text . But if i wants to store the text in the database for this i need the syntax

Comment: example:If i change the Text  - > Treatme into bold italic using the Editor.In the echo statement it must be displaye like this <b><i>treatme</i></b> . IT is Possible

Comment: @Meena, I have updated my answer and code in it. Read the answer now.